# Keep getting this error: could not convert from 'int' to 'std::__cxx11::string' {aka 'std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>'}|

Tags: c++

So I have this project to make a menu for a cinema.

However I keep getting this error: "could not convert 'search_item' from 'int' to 'std::__cxx11::string' {aka 'std::__cxx11::basic_string'}"

This line of code is causing the error: `int found=SearchByMovieName(cinema, c_size, search_item);`

I can't seem to figure out the reason or the solution.

````
  #include <iostream>
  #define t_size 10

  using namespace std;


struct Address
{
  string City;
  int StreetNo;
};

struct movie_type
{
  string name;
  string description;
  int allowed_age;
};

struct Cinema
{
  long ID;
  string Name;
  long long int phone_number;
  struct Address address;
  int rating;
  int hall_numbers;
  struct movie_type movie;
};

void FillData(struct Cinema* cinema, int c_index)
{
  cout << endl<< "Please enter the following details" << endl;
  cout << "ID: ";
  cin>>cinema[c_index].ID;
  cout<< "Name: ";
  cin>>cinema[c_index].Name;
  cout<< "Phone Number: ";
  cin>>cinema[c_index].phone_number;
  cout<< "City: ";
  cin>>cinema[c_index].address.City;
  cout<< "Street Number: ";
  cin>>cinema[c_index].address.StreetNo;
  cout<< "Rating: ";
  cin>>cinema[c_index].rating;
  cout<< "Hall Numbers: ";
  cin>>cinema[c_index].hall_numbers;
  cout<< "Movie Name: ";
  cin>>cinema[c_index].movie.name;
  cout<< "Movie Description: ";
  cin>>cinema[c_index].movie.description;
  cout<< "Allowed Age in Movie: ";
  cin>>cinema[c_index].movie.allowed_age;
  cout<< endl<< "Data filled Successfully."<< endl;
}

void OutData(struct Cinema* cinema, int c_index)
{
  cout<< "ID: "<< cinema[c_index].ID;
  cout<< "\tName: "<< cinema[c_index].Name;
  cout<< endl<< "Phone Number: "<< cinema[c_index].phone_number;
  cout<< endl<< "City: "<< cinema[c_index].address.City;
  cout<< "\tStreet Number: "<< cinema[c_index].address.StreetNo;
  cout<< endl<< "Rating: "<< cinema[c_index].rating;
  cout<< "\tHall Numbers: "<< cinema[c_index].hall_numbers;
  cout<< endl<< "Movie Name: "<< cinema[c_index].movie.name;
  cout<< endl<< "Movie Description: "<< cinema[c_index].movie.description;
  cout<< endl<< "Allowed Age in Movie: "<< cinema[c_index].movie.allowed_age;
  cout<< endl<< endl;
}

int SearchByName(struct Cinema* cinema, int c_size, string Name)
{
  int found=0;
  for(int i=0;i<c_size;i+=1)
{

    if(cinema[i].Name==Name)
    {
      found+=1;
      cout << endl << "Found" <<endl;
      OutData(cinema, i);
    }
}
       return found;
}

int SearchByRating(struct Cinema* cinema, int c_size, int rating)
{
  int found=0;
  for(int i=0;i<c_size;i+=1)
  {

    if(cinema[i].rating==rating)
    {
      found+=1;
      cout << endl << "Found" <<endl;
      OutData(cinema, i);
    }
  }
       return found;
}
int SearchByMovieName(struct Cinema* cinema, int c_size, string mname)
{
    int found=0;
    for(int i=0;i<c_size;i+=1)
{

    if(cinema[i].movie.name==mname)
    {
      found+=1;
      cout << endl << "Found" <<endl;
      OutData(cinema, i);
    }
}
       return found;
}

int SearchByID (struct Cinema* cinema, int c_size, long ID)
{
  int found=0;
  for(int i=0;i<c_size;i+=1)
{

    if(cinema[i].ID==ID)
    {
      found+=1;
      cout << endl << "Found" <<endl;
      OutData(cinema, i);
    }
}
       return found;
}

int SearchByStreetNo(struct Cinema* cinema, int c_size, int StreetNo)
{
  int found=0;
  for(int i=0;i<c_size;i+=1)
{

    if(cinema[i].address.StreetNo==StreetNo)
    {
      found+=1;
      cout << endl << "Found" <<endl;
      OutData(cinema, i);
    }
}
       return found;
}


int main()
{

    struct Cinema cinema[t_size];
    int c_size=0;
    int choice=0;


    do
    {
        cout<< endl<< endl<< "\t\MENU"<<endl<<endl;
        cout<< "Press 1 to fill data of database" <<endl;
        cout<< "Press 2 to output data in the database"<< endl;
        cout<< "Press 3 to search on Cinema by Name" <<endl;
        cout<< "Press 4 to search on Cinema by \"5 \" stars rating"<< endl;
        cout<< "Press 5 to search on Cinema by names of viewing movies"<< endl;
        cout<< "Press 6 to search on Cinema by ID"<< endl;
        cout<< "Press 7 to search on Cinema on StreetNo \"109\" "<< endl;
        cout<< "Press 8 to exit" << endl;
        cout<< endl<< "Enter: "<< endl;
        cin >>choice;




        if(choice==1)
        {
            if(c_size<t_size-1)
            {
                FillData(cinema, c_size);
                c_size+=1;
            }
            else
            {
                cout<< endl<< "No space left!!!"<<endl;
            }
        }
        else if(choice==2)
        {
            for(int i=0;i<c_size;i+=1)
            {
                OutData(cinema, i);
            }
        }
        else if(choice==3)
        {
            string search_item;
            cout<< "Enter Name to search on Cinema: ";
            cin>>search_item;
            int found=SearchByName(cinema, c_size, search_item);
            if(found==0)
            {
                cout<<"Not found!!!"<<endl;
            }
        }
        else if(choice==4)
        {
            int search_item;
            cout<< "Enter rating to search on Cinema: ";
            cin>> search_item;
            int found=SearchByRating(cinema, c_size, search_item);
            if (found==0)
            {
                cout<< "Not Found!!!"<< endl;
            }
        }
        else if(choice==5)
        {
            int search_item;
            cout<< "Enter Viewing Movie Name to search on Cinema: ";
            cin>> search_item;
            ```lang-cpp
            int found=SearchByMovieName(cinema, c_size, search_item);
            ```
            if (found==0)
            {
                cout<< "Not Found!!!"<< endl;

            }
        }
        else if(choice==6)
        {
            int search_item;
            cout<< "Enter ID to search on Cinema: ";
            int found=SearchByID(cinema, c_size, search_item);
            if (found==0)
            {
                cout<< "Not Found!!!"<< endl;

            }
        }
        else if(choice==7)
        {
            int search_item;
            cout << "Street Number to search on Cinema: ";
            int found=SearchByStreetNo(cinema, c_size, search_item);
            if (found==0);
            {
                cout<< "Not Found!!!"<< endl;

            }
        }
        else if(choice==8)
        {
            cout<<endl<< "Thank You!"<<endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cout<<endl<< "Invalid Choice!! Please Try Again!!"<< endl;
        }

    }while(choice!=8);


  return 0;
}
````

Comment: The third parameter to that function -- `search_item` -- is supposed to be a `std::string`, right?  As the error mentions, you're passing an `int`.

Comment: Voting to close as typo because this error looks like caused by improper copy-and-paste of the code.

Comment: _"I can't seem to figure out the reason"_ maybe you're saying that you're having trouble reading/understanding the error message?  It's not entirely clear what isn't entirely clear to you.

Comment: @DrewDormann Yes I'm a beginner in coding and I just got into C++. I'm a bit embarrassed that I missed this tiny mistake. Thank you

Comment: @ReimOss it's not an uncommon mistake when copy-pasting code.  The general solution is _not to copy-paste code_.  Instead of pasting the same code over and over to change a tiny part, look for ways to put repeated code in its own function or functions.  The parts that you were changing would be parameters.  Suddenly your code becomes smaller and easier to manage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

````
else if(choice==5)
    {
        int search_item;
        cout<< "Enter Viewing Movie Name to search on Cinema: ";
        cin>> search_item;
        ```lang-cpp
        int found=SearchByMovieName(cinema, c_size, search_item);
        ```
        if (found==0)
        {
            cout<< "Not Found!!!"<< endl;

        }
    }
````

SearchByMovieName takes string as third parameter but search_item is declared as int here.